# Arrange Header's Data VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on a sheet of data with several headers and I would like to arrange each header in a specific column.

My issue right now is that I have several headers througout the rows and I am only able to arrange the headers by the first set of headers in the first row and not in all the rows.

In every column and rows there are headers, I would like to have the respective data under the same header for each column.

The code I am using right now that only allows to me to arrange the columns by the first row of columns is the following:

```
Sub CopyHeadersColumns()

'Set the column heading you want. Add as many as you want, comma seperated
'The order you enter determines the order they appear on the second sheet
Dim Titles As Variant
Titles = Array("/@codeInsee", "/Nom", "/CoordonnéesNum/Télécopie", "/CoordonnéesNum/Téléphone", "/Ouverture/PlageJ/@début", "/Ouverture/PlageJ/@fin", "/Ouverture/PlageJ/PlageH/@début", "/Ouverture/PlageJ/PlageH/@fin")

Dim i As Long 'Counter

For i = 0 To UBound(Titles)

    'Select Full Report Sheet
    Sheets(1).Select

    'Find Notes column and copy. If it can't find the title, will move to the next.
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
        Cells.Find(What:=Titles(i), After:=Range("A1"), _
        LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns).EntireColumn.Copy
    On Error GoTo 0

    'Select Secondary Report sheet, column E and paste
    Sheets(2).Select
    Range("A1").Offset(0, i).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

NextOne:
Next i

Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
Resume NextOne

End Sub
```

Comment: You seem to be asking a very similar question every couple of weeks.  I think you need to describe the process from start to end as I don't think you are going about it the right way.

Comment: Hi @Gareth Thanks for the comment, I have changed my question, hopefully is clearly now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have the titles already as headers for columns in the second sheet, please see if this helps, I've added comments in the code for more details:

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub CopyHeadersColumns()

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .DisplayAlerts = False
End With

With ActiveWorkbook
    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet: Set wsSrc = .Sheets("Sheet1")
    Dim wsDst As Worksheet: Set wsDst = .Sheets("Sheet2")
End With

Dim arrTitles As Variant
arrTitles = Array("/@codeInsee", "/Nom", "/CoordonnéesNum/Télécopie", "/CoordonnéesNum/Téléphone", "/Ouverture/PlageJ/@début", "/Ouverture/PlageJ/@fin", "/Ouverture/PlageJ/PlageH/@début", "/Ouverture/PlageJ/PlageH/@fin")

Dim arrData As Variant, arrDstTitles As Variant, arrCols() As Long
Dim R As Long, C As Long, X As Long, Y As Long, lRowSrc As Long, lColSrc As Long, lRowDst As Long

arrDstTitles = wsDst.Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, wsDst.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column)

Dim dicTitles As Object
Set dicTitles = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

'Allocate the column number of the destination title to the dictionary for reuse
For X = LBound(arrTitles) To UBound(arrTitles)
    For Y = LBound(arrDstTitles, 2) To UBound(arrDstTitles, 2)
        If arrTitles(X) = arrDstTitles(1, Y) Then
            dicTitles(arrTitles(X)) = Y
            Exit For
        End If
    Next Y
Next X


With wsSrc
    lRowSrc = .UsedRange.Rows.Count 'get the last row in the source worksheet
    lColSrc = .UsedRange.Columns.Count 'get the last column in the source worksheet
    arrData = .Cells(1, 1).Resize(lRowSrc, lColSrc) 'get the data into an array

    For R = LBound(arrData) To UBound(arrData)
        For C = LBound(arrData, 2) To UBound(arrData, 2)
            'Check if row is a title
            If dicTitles.Exists(arrData(R, C)) Then 'title found
                If X <> R Then ReDim arrCols(1 To lColSrc) 'redimensionate the array to hold the column number of the destination
                X = R 'save the row of the title
                arrCols(C) = dicTitles(arrData(R, C))
            ElseIf Not X = R And Not IsEmpty(arrData(R, C)) And Not arrCols(C) = 0 Then
                With wsDst
                    If C = 1 Then lRowDst = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                    .Cells(lRowDst, arrCols(C)).Value = arrData(R, C)
                End With
            End If
        Next C
    Next R
End With

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .DisplayAlerts = True
End With

End Sub
```

**EDIT:** changed the code based on new input from OP.

Comment: Hello @FAB your code edit works fine, but I'm having some problems, I would like to know how can I modify the code for it to respect it respective order on each row?
The code is copying successfully the data under the headers, but it seems to be skipping some cells in the process and as a result the information does not match.

Comment: @Pod you'll have to a lot more specific about "in order" means for you. Considering you have repeating headers, seemingly random across the sheet, my code picks them up in what Excel considers the order of `Find`, starting from previous `Find` range. so if you want all rows from column A, then column B, etc say that. If you want all column values from Row1, then Row2, etc, then say that. Otherwise how would you expect anyone to guess the order?

Comment: I apologize for the misunderstanding @FAB . I would like to have the value from every Row due that each Row corresponds to a specific location. To explain a little bit more about my data: Each set of headers represent the information from a location, not every location has the same header nor on the same order, but the headers I'm interested on all appear throughout all locations. I would like to have the value from every Row in each Column so once the Headers are arranged I am still able to see the correct location’s data.

Comment: As a follow-up to this process I will use the schedules’ headers which are divided in 4 different headers to set up a function that shows me if a location is open or closed. I need the headers arranged so I can run the function through the entire columns. This last part is already done but I am detailing it so you can have a better scope of my project.  @FAB

Comment: I`m sorry @Pod, but I`m still not more clear on what you want the final result to look like. If you can, please provide a screenshot side by side, of current sample data, and how you want it to look finally, then i`ll change the code to match that.

Comment: I have added a picture link "Result Picture Example" on top of the page. This picture is an example of the result. Each cell data from Row1 is specific from Row1, each data found in Row2 is specific from Row2, and so on. Hope this picture helps clarify my issue and thank you for the help. @FAB

Comment: @Pod i think it makes more sense now, even if you have headers all over, they are still relating to each other on the same row.... I`ll update my code when i get home.

Comment: @Pod see updated code, I think now it does what you want it do. I assume (hope) that at least "/@codeInsee" is a static column (always in A), otherwise might need some further tweaks.

Comment: Hello @FAB You are right, it is static in column A. The vba code works perfectly! Thank you for your time and help, I was stucked in this part of the project for weeks.